# javascript で イベント定義する際に"Type Error: element.addEventLestener is not a function"となってしまい、イベント定義ができません。

Tags: javascript

現在、素のJavaScriptでイベントリスナーを登録しようとしているのですが、"addEventLestener"自体が関数として認識されていないようです。

元となるオブジェクトはHTML要素で、`var isbn = document.getElementsByName("isbn");`　と記述しました。

`Object.values(isbn);` で要素を取得できているのか確認したところ、要素の取得はうまくいっているようです。

コードは以下になります。

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    var isbn = document.getElementsByName('isbn');
    console.log(Object.values(isbn));
    getBookData(isbn);

}, false);

function getBookData(element){

    element.addEventListener('change', function(){
        // 処理
    }, false);

}
```

そして、取得しているHTML要素は以下になります。

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="isbn" maxlength="13" value="" placeholder="" required>
```

Answer (score 4):

`get​Elements​ByName` メソッドの返り値は **`NodeList` オブジェクト**です。

> #### § 3.1.3 DOM tree accessors<sup>[[1]](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#dom-tree-accessors)</sup>
>
> The getElementsByName(name) method takes a string name, and must return a live NodeList containing all the HTML elements in that document that have a name attribute whose value is equal to the name argument (in a case-sensitive manner), in tree order.

`Node` インターフェイスは `EventTarget` インターフェイスを継承しています<sup>[[2]](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#node)</sup>が、`NodeList` インターフェイスは `EventTarget` インターフェイスを継承していません<sup>[[3]](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#nodelist)</sup>。

そのため、質問文のコードを動作させるためには、 **`NodeList` オブジェクト内の各 `Node` に対して、 `addEventListener` メソッドを適用する**処理を行わなければなりません。

```js
window.addEventListener(
  "DOMContentLoaded",
  function() {
    var isbn = document.getElementsByName("isbn");
    getBookData(isbn);
  },
  false
);

function getBookData(element) {
  element.forEach(e => {
    e.addEventListener(
      "change",
      function() {
        console.log(e.value);
      },
      false
    );
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="isbn" maxlength="13" value="" placeholder="" required>
```

---

参考:

1. [HTML Standard - § 3.1.3 DOM tree accessors](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#dom-tree-accessors)
2. [DOM Standard - § 4.4. Interface Node](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#node)
3. [DOM Standard - § 4.2.10.1. Interface NodeList](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#nodelist)